# IBM Container Plugin for cf CLI has issues with proxy

Tags: proxy, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

We can do a `cf login` in an environment that requires an (HTTP) proxy. But `cf ic login` fails. Is there something else we have to do? We were able to use `cf ic login` when switching to another network that doesn't use a proxy but that is no long term solution.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment?

Comment: Hello, have you tried if ice client is having the same problem? Following a guide to setup this kind of client https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html#container_cli_ice_ov

Comment: Could you please update your question and add the error output of cf ic login when using the Proxy environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an HTTP proxy server on your network between a host running the cf CLI and your Cloud Foundry API endpoint, you must set HTTP_PROXY with the hostname or IP address of the proxy server.

The HTTP_PROXY environment variable holds the hostname or IP address of your proxy server.

HTTP_Proxy is a standard environment variable. Like any environment variable, the specific steps you use to set it depends on your operating system.

For setting your http proxy, you should follow the instructions described at

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/http-proxy.html